# Update cell value with prefix + counter with single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with a column `CName` which contain person names.

If I want to annomynize this column so that the value are updated to become "Person 001", "Person 002", ..., "Person n".

Would this be possible with MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following way:

```
update users,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r set users.name=concat('Person ',@rownum:=@rownum+1);
```